# Loading All Cell Values Of Same Clicked Row in a Table into an Array But First and Last <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/gjt5n1k1/3/) and let me know how I can load all cell values in selected `.adder` clicked row **BUT** First `<td>` and Last `<td>` and instead add also the `user` and `today` to the array as well?

```js
var arr = [];
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var today = d.getFullYear() + '/' + ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
var user = "foo";

$(".adder").on("click", function(){
   console.log($(this).closest('tr').children('td').text());
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
body{padding:30px;}
.adder{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Jill</td>  
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
     <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus adder" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Eve</td>  
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
     <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus adder" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use **.each()** and loop through `td`  and then you need **.push()** to create an array

```
var arr = [];
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var today = d.getFullYear() + '/' + ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
var user = "foo";

$(".adder").on("click", function(){
 var $this = $(this);
    var getarray = [];
$this.closest('tr').find('td').not($this.closest('tr').find('td:first')).not($this.closest('tr').find('td:last')).each(function(){
    getarray.push($(this).text());
});
    getarray.push(user);
    getarray.push(today);
    alert(getarray);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/gjt5n1k1/6/)

Note : In this code I used .not() for first td which equal 1 and last td .. is that what you want??

this is another way by using :not instead of .not() in js

```
$this.closest('tr').find('td:not(td:first, td:last)').each(function(){});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/gjt5n1k1/7/)

Comment: Thanks Mohamed but how about `user` and `today` plus it is not in the array!